# Rails : How to query a field in a associated table when the foreign_key now following the convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, querying

**Tables**

*claims* belongs_to *towns*

**Model**

The foreign key isn't following the convention as it is much clearer and I should have multiple relations to the same table in the future.

```
class Claim < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :risk_town,    class_name: "Town"
end
```

**Query**

When I try to get claims filtered by town postal code, I use this query :

```
Claim.joins(:risk_town).where(risk_town:{postal_code:70000})
```

Got this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: risk_town.postal_code
SELECT "claims".* FROM "claims" INNER JOIN "towns" ON "towns"."id" = "claims"."risk_town_id" WHERE "risk_town"."postal_code" = ?  [["postal_code", "70000"]]
```

I don't understand why rails doesn't alias "towns" to match my relation name "risk_town".

What are the workaround is this case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
Claim.joins(:risk_town).where(towns:{postal_code:70000})
```

Table name is `towns` not `risk_town`

Inside `joins` you specify association, inside `where` you specify table name

Comment: No, there is no table "risk_towns". There is a table "towns".  A Claim belong to a Town with a relation name "risk_town" (and a foreign key risk_town_id)

Comment: It was not what I search for. This is what i've understand : With rails 4.2.3 it's not possible to change the join SQL alias. It is decided by rails. The first time the table is joined, the name of the table is used. The second, third... times the join is aliases with the relation name given in the "belongs_to" concatened with the model name. Here it would be : "risk_town_claims"